# Javascript: Find value of an element in tag by classname

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
<tr style="background: rgb(243, 236, 236);">
   <td style="width:20%;">1:0</td>
   <td style="width:70%;"><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-random"></i></span><span class="Pattern">Geometric Decomposition</span></td>
   <td style="width:10%;">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td style="width:20%;">1:11</td>
   <td style="width:70%;"><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i></span><span class="Pattern">Pipeline</span></td>
   <td style="width:10%;">1</td>
</tr>
```

**UPDATE**
I am iterating through the table rows to get the value in `class="Pattern"` while also reading the value of the first cell (ID e.g. `1:01`). My current javascript code:

```
 nodeIds = []
 nodePatterns = []
for(i = 0; i < tds.length; ++i) {
    var cells = tds[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    nodeIds.push(cells[0].innerHTML);
    nodePatterns.push(cells[1].innerHTML);
}
```

But with `cells[1].innerHTML` I just get the following values:

1. `<span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-random"></i></span><span class="Pattern">Geometric Decomposition</span>`
2. `<span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i></span><span class="Pattern">Pipeline</span>`
   Now I am looking for a way to get the value of tag `span` with `class="Pattern"` i.e. Geometric Decomposition and Pipeline. I could use javascript functions like `indexOf`... but I was looking for a more elegant way to solve this problem by calling the tags with their tag name.
   Is their a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function **[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** which selects the first found element.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('table tr td span.Pattern').textContent)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width:70%;">
   <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-random"></i></span>
   <span class="Pattern">Geometric Decomposition</span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

If you need to get access to multiple `span` elements, you can use the function **[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** which returns a NodeList of found elements.

To get the first TD, you can go up using the function `closest` and then execute the function `querySelector`.

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('table tr td span.Pattern'), function(span) {
  console.log(span.closest('tr').querySelector('td').textContent);
  console.log(span.textContent);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background: rgb(243, 236, 236);">
      <td style="width:20%;">1:0</td>
      <td style="width:70%;"><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-random"></i></span><span class="Pattern">Geometric Decomposition</span></td>
      <td style="width:10%;">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:20%;">1:11</td>
      <td style="width:70%;"><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i></span><span class="Pattern">Pipeline</span></td>
      <td style="width:10%;">1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The second part works for me. But that seems that I have to change my code using the loop. I would like to keep the loop, because while iterating I am also reading the value of the first cell of each row. Is there a way to read the value of the second cell while iterating thru the tablerows and just extract the value of the `class="Pattern"` part?

Answer (score 4):

```
document.querySelector('.pattern')
```

or to be more specific than that, possibly

```
document.querySelector('span.Pattern')
```

The getElementsBy* methods return HTMLCollections, which can be difficult to work with. When you want collections, consider using querySelectorAll instead, which returns a static NodeList - unlike an HTMLCollection, it can be iterated over directly, it won't change while it's being iterated over, and it's much more flexible.

Or, when you're just selecting one element, just use .querySelector.

Another side note: unless you want to get HTML markup in particular, it's generally easier to use `.textContent` rather than `.innerHTML`.